# MPMoviePlayerController Streaming Video won't play Audio

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm streaming video to my app with MPMoviePlayerController, works great in Simulator and my device, but one of my beta testers devices won't play the audio. Audio controls won't appear, and instead, show the following image:

[image]

Any idea what is going on? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Wow... I apologize for being a dummy. Turns out their device was on vibrate... sorry for wasting anyones time. If someone wants to answer with "Turn the vibrate off, Dummy!"... then I'll approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beta testers phone was on vibrate... dummy.